Big data transfer between two hard drives freezes + following problems?
I already did a research but did not find any helpful information to my problem.
I have a laptop on windows 10 since several years and got a quite new computer that I decided to put Ubuntu Studio (24.04) to be my main workstation for audio productions and small video. I am new to linux environment, and start to get used to the basics. The computer is 12th gen Intel core i5-12600K with 16Go RAM.
I have a 2TO hard drive for my data and a second 2TO for cloning this same data. I have both in NTFS and struggle a lot to copy files. When I was copying big amounts of files (around 15 000 files) the process always freezes at some point. I tried several manners inside dolphin or using Grsync (Gui). It always freezed with large amount of files, with smaller amounts of files its working ok, but this would be to problematic as I would need to copy manually all the folders, not a solution.
The first question would be : what do you do when everything freezes when in a file copy process?
Everything was frozen, mouse and everything, I could do nothing than do a hard reset on the computer case itself. Of course when the system restarted ubuntu does not want to mount the hard drive anymore. So what I did is plug it in to the windows and did the repair process in windows, which worked and Ubuntu could see it again and mount it again.
I did this several times!
So I am still at the same point, I need to have an efficient workflow copying files between this drives without freezing. How can I troubleshoot this and resolve this problem?
I started a "badblocks" analyze on one of this hard drives, for now (70% - took me already 2 days!)) it does not show any errors. But I am really out of ideas to fix this.
Maybe I should format this drives in ext format but I will need to copy all this data again and the risk of freezing is still there.
Thanks very much for your help.

copy using cp? if so switch to rsync. It has resume .... and the issue is likely the ntfs driver.

Search this site for "slow copy" or "low data transfer rate". System buffers fill up when writes are slower than reads (the usual case), and things grind to a crawl with little free memory. Workarounds are suggested for specific cases.
